# Does using thinner glasses have any effect on how the eye look?

Tags: optics, refraction, lenses, glass

My daughter asked me to buy thin glasses for her eyes. So the power of the lenses are the same, but the glasses are thinner because the glasses use plastic with higher refraction index.

Latter I found out that she does that because she think thinner glasses will make her eyes look more normal rather than small.

I told her that's not possible.

She shows me this link

[https://www.theoptical.co/see/why-do-my-eyes-look-smaller-with-glasses#:~:text=Choose%20The%20Right%20Material&text=Generally%20speaking%2C%20the%20thinner%20the,your%20eyes%20to%20look%20smaller](https://www.theoptical.co/see/why-do-my-eyes-look-smaller-with-glasses#:%7E:text=Choose%20The%20Right%20Material&text=Generally%20speaking%2C%20the%20thinner%20the,your%20eyes%20to%20look%20smaller)

> Generally speaking, the thinner the lens, the less minification
> caused. This doesn’t always mean that every prescription needs to
> upgrade to the thinnest lens possible, but the wrong eyeglass lens
> material can cause your eyes to look smaller.

I think she's wrong.

While thinner glasses may look more elegant because the glass itself is thin. For the same dioptri it will not change how your eyes look.

Which one is right?

Comment: Given that the 'look' is an overall impression of the face, and big thick glasses change the overall impression of the face, I'd say that yes, it changes your look. In my case the driving factor is my glasses' weight and balance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that could play a role is the validity of the [*thin lens approximation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_lens) - this likely guides the reasoning for why thick and thin lenses should produce the same effect, but it is less applicable to thick lenses. However, at the moment, I am not sure how one could estimate the importance of the effect.

Related: [Lens Formula for thick lens](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/484322/247642)

Comment: The easiest way to convince you or your daughter is just let her try it out at a good optician. Even if we give a more physical explanation , she will not believe it. And take some friend of her along tu judge.